# When to use Data Factory (copy) over direct pull in SQL synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, data-warehouse, polybase, azure-synapse

I am just going through some Microsoft Document and doing handOn for Data engineering related things.
I have couple of queries for a scenrerio - "copy CSV file(s) from Blob storage to Synapse analytics (stage table(s)):

I read that we can do direct data pull in Synapse with the process of creating external tables. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-wideworldimportersdw)

If above is possible, then in what cases we do use Azure Data factory Copy or data flow method?
While working with Azure data factory, is it a good idea to use Polybase, because it will use Blob storage again as staging in this scenrerio (i.e. I am copying file from Blob only and again using blob for staging)?

I searched for answers to my queries but haven't found any satisfactory answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just straight loading data from CSV into DW, use Copy. Polybase is recommended, but not always needed for small files.

If you need to transform that data or perform updates, then use data flows.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the response.  I am clear with Copy and data flow within Data factory.                                                So, in what cases we do use direct import in Synapse (with creating external tables and all) over data factory process? Just taking a scenrerio, where we need to load data dump (i.e. one time activity for all tables of a DB)...now in this case what should be preferred Data factory or direct pull in Synapse. And why?